# R/GIS: Find orthogonal distance between a location and nearest line

Tags: r, gis

I am trying to find the orthogonal distance between a set of location coordinates and a set of lines (roads or rivers). The set of points are in the form of latitude/longitude pairs, and the lines are in a shapefile (.shp). Plotting them on a map is not a problem, using either `maptools` or `PBSmapping`. But my basic problem is to find the minimum distance one has to travel from a location to reach a road or a river. Is there any way to do this in R?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can do this simply enough with `gDistance` in the `rgeos` package.

Read in the lines as `SpatialLines/DataFrame` and points as `SpatialPoints/DataFrame` and then loop over each point calculating the distance each time:

```
require(rgeos)
## untested code
shortest.dists <- numeric(nrow(sp.pts))
for (i in seq_len(nrow(sp.pts)) {
    shortest.dists[i] <- gDistance(sp.pts[i,], sp.lns)
}
```

Here `sp.pts` is the Spatial points object, and `sp.lns` is the Spatial lines object.

You must loop so that you only compare a single coordinate in `sp.pts` with the entirety of all lines geometries in `sp.lns`, otherwise you get the distance from an aggregate value across all points.

Since your data are in latitude/longitude you should transform both the lines and points to a suitable projection since the `gDistance` function assumes Cartesian distance.

MORE DISCUSSION AND EXAMPLE (edit)

It would be neat to get the nearest point on the line/s rather than just the distance, but this opens another option which is whether you need the nearest *coordinate* along a line, or an actual *intersection* with a line segment that is closer than any existing vertex. If your vertices are dense enough that the difference doesn't matter, then use `spDistsN1` in the `sp` package. You'd have to extract all the coordinates from every line in the set (not hard, but a bit ugly) and then loop over each point of interest calculating the distance to the line vertices - then you can find which is the shortest and select that coordinate from the set of vertices, so you can have the distance and the coordinate easily. There's no need to project either since the function can use ellipsoidal distances with `longlat = TRUE` argument.

```
library(maptools)

## simple global data set, which we coerce to Lines
data(wrld_simpl)

wrld_lines <- as(wrld_simpl, "SpatialLinesDataFrame")

## get every coordinate as a simple matrix (scary but quick)
wrld_coords <- do.call("rbind", lapply(wrld_lines@lines, function(x1) do.call("rbind", lapply(x1@Lines, function(x2) x2@coords[-nrow(x2@coords), ]))))
```

Check it out interactively, you'll have to modify this to save the coords or minimum distances. This will plot up the lines and wait for you to click anywhere in the plot, then it will draw a line from your click to the nearest *vertex* on a line.

```
## no out of bounds clicking . . .
par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0), xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i") 

plot(wrld_lines, asp = "")

n <- 5

for (i in seq_len(n)) {
xy <- matrix(unlist(locator(1)), ncol = 2)
    all.dists <- spDistsN1(wrld_coords, xy, longlat = TRUE)
    min.index <- which.min(all.dists)
    points(xy, pch = "X")
lines(rbind(xy, wrld_coords[min.index, , drop = FALSE]), col = "green", lwd = 2)
}
```

Comment: Nice and informative answer. Thanks for that. It looks like `rgeos` doesn't have any function that returns the (or a) closest location. Do you happen to have a suggestion for a function that does? It looks like `project2segment()` in `spatstat` does this, but it unfortunately doesn't use `sp` class objects, which would be handier...

Comment: I'll update, I was thinking about this more and there are a few subtleties.

Comment: converting between spatstat and sp is not hard, there are coercion tools in maptools, such as spst <- as.psp(wrld_lines)

Comment: Awesome demo in your "MORE DISCUSSION" section. I hope everyone with any interest in this takes a minute to run that code. Also, thanks for the pointer to the full suite of `sp -> spatstat -> sp` conversion tools in the `maptools` package.

Comment: mdsumner... truly, TRULY ingenious. Many thanks. This has to be one of the most original ideas ever on stackoverflow.

Comment: @mdsumner Awesome answer.  taRifx.geo has `SLDFtoLine` to simplify SpatialLines to matrix conversion, and `interpolatePathpoints` to add points between vertices to improve the point density of your lines.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman "Package ‘taRifx.geo’ was removed from the CRAN repository"

Answer (score 4):

The `geosphere` package has the dist2line function that does this for lon/lat data. It can use Spatial* objects or matrices.

```
line <- rbind(c(-180,-20), c(-150,-10), c(-140,55), c(10, 0), c(-140,-60))
pnts <- rbind(c(-170,0), c(-75,0), c(-70,-10), c(-80,20), c(-100,-50), 
         c(-100,-60), c(-100,-40), c(-100,-20), c(-100,-10), c(-100,0))
d <- dist2Line(pnts, line)
d
```

Illustration of the results

```
plot( makeLine(line), type='l')
points(line)
points(pnts, col='blue', pch=20)
points(d[,2], d[,3], col='red', pch='x')
for (i in 1:nrow(d)) lines(gcIntermediate(pnts[i,], d[i,2:3], 10), lwd=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this can be done in the `sf` package using the `st_distance` function.

You pass your two `sf` objects to the function. Same issue as with the other solutions in that you need to iterate over your points so that the function calculates the distance between every point to every point on the roadways. Then take the minimum of the resulting vector for the shortest distance.

```
# Solution for one point
min(st_distance(roads_sf, points_sf[1, ]))

# Iterate over all points using sapply
sapply(1:nrow(points_sf), function(x) min(st_distance(roads_sf, points_sf[x, ])))
```